Judge Judy episode in which man who sues a lot of people is countersued; damages increased to $5000
I'm looking for a specific Judge Judy scene I'd like to watch again. A man is suing a woman over a customer service issue: I think she was a cashier.
(For identification: the man was probably in his early forties, the woman was late twenties and I think accompanied by another woman, possibly her mother. All three were white.)
She was counter suing him for a small amount to cover her expenses.
Judge Judy discovered that he sued many people and had missed a previous court hearing to sue the defendant because he had a double booked court case (ie he was suing someone else at the same time). She threw out his case and increased the countersuit amount to the maximum $5000.
Update: This episode appears to be from one of the first four seasons (1996 - 2000). This conclusion is from @Walt's comment which has found a reference to this episode on this old page:

SUPERMARKET MAYHEM A woman gave a man the wrong change at the grocery store, but later corrected her mistake.  She was brought to court by the guy because he wanted to teach her a lesson.  Judge Judy thought the lawsuit was a fraud and a waste of court time and granted the cashier more money than she asked for.  She and her friend cheered at the decision.

Update 2: the episode was also mentioned on this discussion board:

She has gone above standard rulings before though. My favorite case (that I've unfortunately never been able to fine online) was when a guy sued a cashier for giving him the wrong change. She countersued for slander because the guy went off on her and called her a thief at her work. 
She ruled in the cashier's favor, gave her more than she asked for, and then fined the guy above that for wasting the court's time.

It is also mentioned in this Amazon review:

There is one case I am hoping for.
It is where a man is suing a cashier who gave him the wrong change on Christmas Eve.
That one just sticks out in my mind as the best one ever.

Update 3: according to moviefone, Season 2 Episode 8 (17 September 1997) is:

Supermarket checker sued.

Unfortunately I cannot confirm that and this site appears to have some errors (repetitions in some episode descriptions) and ideally I'd like a video or at least one other source to confirm it.

It does seem to be from the first 4 seasons, which are unfortunately not really indexed online. FWIW, it's listed as 'Supermarket Mayhem' in this page (scroll to the bottom).

@Walt: That's it! If you can add the episode number I will accept the answer. Great find!

That's the thing, though. I can't find the episode number (or even the season it's in) anywhere. But at least it's a start. ;)

Came across that moviefone link too after commenting but like you said, it's not conclusive. However, it's probably your safest bet?
